# how to Excel data converts user format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new at work. I would like to convert Excel file from 3rd party to out format. I don't ask whole code, I would like to have advise from you. For example, what functions I need or what features in Excel I can use.

```
     A         B              C     D        E     
1   Code    category       Bid     Ask     close   
2   H2       IG9          15.92    16.8     17.6
3   H6       AP8          11.22    18.2     18.2
4   H3       CD5          12.34    22.1     34.2
5  ....
```

Once VBA script runs.. date should be converted following format.

```
H2++^||IG9++^||15.92++^||16.8++^||17.6++^||
H6++^||AP8++^||11.22++^||18.2++^||18.2++^||
H3++^||CD5++^||12.34++^||22.1++^||34.2++^||
```

I'm looking forward to discuss you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Join() function specifying "++^||" as delimeter

```
Sub Convert()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim delim As String

    delim = "++^||"
    For Each cell In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight)).value)), delim) & delim
    Next
End Sub
```